# Is there a conventional symbolic expression for the set of analytic functions?

Tags: functions, notation

Is there a conventional symbolic way of saying "$f$ is analytic" analogous to how one can say "$f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$" for real-valued functions with continuous derivatives of all orders?

Comment: I’ve seen $C^{\omega}$ sometimes. $\mathcal{O}$ seems standard for *complex*-analytic functions.

Comment: @Aphelli OK, thanks.